# Wordpress status 500 but no output on screen with plugins gone in directory and theme functions reset

Tags: wordpress

I am really freaking out. A minute ago, I was just adding do_shortcode on theme catch-katmandu and clicked the update button. It didn't give me feedback at all and the screen went totally blank. The last plugin I installed was Feedzy RSS but it is not even in the plugins directory anymore.

I see in network diagnosis, the output is 500 but there is nothing on the screen. I accessed it via FileZilla and noticed all my plugins are gone and that the katchmandu edits are also gone.

How to get it to run again?

Comment: You can manually download your current theme separately and use FileZilla to replace the current theme folder with the freshly downloaded theme. It will only remove all your customization of themes and will not impact any of the database entries.

Comment: I already renamed the themes and plugins directory...no change. Whats worse...i never deleted my plugins and 2017 directory of uploads directory is as well gone.